# javascript function says that is undefined

Tags: javascript, function, defined

all I've written a function in order to calculate many things,

so I've put the value of my vars in input of type hidden, so we have this code:

```
 <input type="hidden" id="p1" value="5000.00">
 <input type="hidden" id="p2" value="5000.01">
 <input type="hidden" id="p3" value="8000.00">
 <input type="hidden" id="p4" value="8000.01">
 <input type="hidden" id="t1" value="15.0">
 <input type="hidden" id="t2" value="12.0">
 <input type="hidden" id="t3" value="6.0">
 <input type="hidden" id="versement" value="12554.35">
 <input type="hidden" id="type" value="d">
```

Moreover, I've have the following code, first an input in order to write the amount to be calculated:

and the function on the top:

so we have:

```
 <script language="text/javascript">
 function hono(p1,p2,p3,p4,t1,t2,t3,type,versement,montantacompte)
 {
     var p1             = document.getElementById("p1").value;
     var p2             = document.getElementById("p2").value;
     var p3             = document.getElementById("p3").value;
     var p4             = document.getElementById("p4").value;
     var t1             = document.getElementById("t1").value;
     var t2             = document.getElementById("t2").value;
     var t3             = document.getElementById("t3").value;
     var type           = document.getElementById("type").value;    
     var versement      = document.getElementById("versement").value;
     var montantacompte = document.getElementById("montantacompte").value;

     if (type== "d")
        {
            if(versement== 0 && montantacompte <= p1)
            {
                reste1= montantacompte;
                pc= t1/100;
                taux1= pc+1;
                h1=((reste1*taux1)+reste1);
                honoraires=h1;
                document.getElementById('taux-1').value=taux1;
                document.getElementById('palier1').value=h1;
                document.getElementById('sommehonoraires').value=honoraires;
            }
            else if(versement < p1 && (versement + acompte) <= p1)
            {
                reste1= montantacompte;
                pc= t1/100;
                taux1= pc+1;
                h1= (reste1*taux1)-reste1;
                honoraires= h1;
                document.getElementById('taux-1').value=taux1;
                document.getElementById('palier1').value=h1;
                document.getElementById('sommehonoraires').value=honoraires;
            }
            else if(versement <= p1 && (versement+montantacompte)>= p2 && (versement+montantacompte)<=p3)
            {
                reste1=p1-versement;
                pc=t1/100;
                taux1=pc+1;
                h1=(reste1*taux1)-reste1;
                reste2=montantacompte-reste1;
                pc2=t2/100;
                taux2=pc2+1;
                h2=(reste2*taux2)-reste2;
                honoraires=h1+h2;
                document.getElementById('taux-1').value=taux1;
                document.getElementById('palier1').value=h1;
                document.getElementById('taux-2').value=taux2;
                document.getElementById('palier-2').value=h2;
                document.getElementById('sommehonoraires').value=honoraires;
            }
            else if (versement==0 && montantacompte>=p2 && montantacompte <=p3)
            {
                reste2=montantacompte-p1;
                reste1=p1;
                pc=(t1/100);
                taux1=pc+1;
                h1=((reste1*taux1)-reste1);
                pc2=(t2/100);
                taux2=pc2+1;
                h2=((reste2*taux2)-reste2);
                honoraires=(h1+h2);
                document.getElementById('taux-1').value=taux1;
                document.getElementById('palier1').value=h1;
                document.getElementById('taux-2').value=taux2;
                document.getElementById('palier2').value=h2;
                document.getElementById('sommehonoraires').value=honoraires;
            }
            else if(versement<=p3 && versement>=p2 && (versement+montantacompte)>=p2 && (versement+montantacompte)<=$3)
            {
            reste1=montantacompte;
            pc=($2/100);
            taux1=pc+1;
            h1=((reste1*taux1)-reste1);
            honoraires=h1;  
            document.getElementById('taux-1').value=taux1;
            document.getElementById('palier1').value=h1;
            document.getElementById('sommehonoraires').value=honoraires;
            }
            else if(versement>=p2 && versement<=p3 && (versement+montantacompte)>=p4)
            {
            reste1=p4-versement;
            pc=(t2/100);
            taux2=pc+1;
            h2=((reste1*taux2)-reste1);
            reste2=montantacompte-reste1;
            pc2=(t3/100);
            taux3=pc2+1;
            h3=((reste2*taux3)-reste2);
            honoraires=(h2+h3);
            document.getElementById('taux-3').value=taux3;
            document.getElementById('palier3').value=h3;
            document.getElementById('taux-2').value=taux2;
            document.getElementById('palier2').value=h2;
            document.getElementById('sommehonoraires').value=honoraires;
        }
        else if(versement==0 && montantacompte>=p4)
        {
            reste1=p1;
            reste2=p3-p2;
            pc=(t1/100);
            taux1=pc+1;
            h1=((reste1*taux1)-reste1);
            pc2=(t2/100);
            taux2=pc2+1;
            h2=((reste2*taux2)-reste2);
            reste3=(montantacompte-reste1-reste2);
            pc3=(t3/100);
            taux3=pc3+1;
            h3=((reste3*$taux3)-reste3);
            honoraires=(h1+h2+h3);
            document.getElementById('taux-1').value=taux1;
            document.getElementById('palier1').value=h1;
            document.getElementById('taux-3').value=taux3;
            document.getElementById('palier3').value=h3;
            document.getElementById('taux-2').value=taux2;
            document.getElementById('palier2').value=h2;
            document.getElementById('sommehonoraires').value=honoraires;
        }
    else if(versement>=p4)
        {
            reste3=montantacompte;
            pc3=($3/100);
            taux3=pc3+1;
            h3=((reste3*taux3)-reste3);
            honoraires=(h3);
            document.getElementById('taux-3').value=taux3;
            document.getElementById('palier3').value=h3;
            document.getElementById('sommehonoraires').value=honoraires;
        }
    }
    if (type=="l")
    {
    pc1=(t1/100);
    taux1=pc1+1;
    honoraires=montantacompte*taux1;
    document.getElementById('taux-1').value=taux1;
    document.getElementById('palier1').value=h1;
    document.getElementById('sommehonoraires').value=honoraires;
    }
 }

 </script><input type="text" name="montantacompte" id="montantacompte" onKeyUp="hono(p1,p2,p3,p4,t1,t2,t3,type,versement,montantacompte)"  />
```

And in the console it says to me that the function is not defined, or it is, because i've written it...
All is in the body.

We have this in the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: hono is not defined test.php:166
>   onkeyup

and the line 166 is where there is the input type text after the function.

sorry for my bad English,

If you need more precisions, just ask me,

Comment: Probably not relevant, but your `script` tag should not have a `language` attribute.  You mean `type`, not `language`.  I doubt that could be causing your exact error, but it is something worth fixing.

Comment: @RayToal I bet thats whats causing it.

Comment: @Musa ah yeah now I remember I have seen some browsers hork on bad attributes.  I once saw an old Firefox script break on `text/javscript` (note the missing `a`).  This is why I never, EVER, use the `type` attribute.  Well, unless I use CoffeeScript....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`language="text/javascript"` is wrong it should be `language="JavaScript"` but thats old/outdated/obsolete/depreciated so use `type="text/javascript"` instead

Comment: thank you so much, i've been looking for what's wrong since 48 hours... Now I can sleep Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, I noticed you have your script attributes wrong.

```
 <script language="text/javascript">
```

should be:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: thanks, I have a standard question, is there a way i can limit the displaying of the results, because it write me 15.20540058505 I would like to have if it is possible two number after the coma. thanks