# Calling JavaScript from ASP

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I have a line of code:

```
Response.write("<script language=""text/JavaScript"">alert(""What up dog"");</script>")
```

This doesn't work.  I see no alert box, yet I see the page source has written the code correctly:

```
<script language="text/JavaScript">alert("What up dog");</script>
```

What I'm actually trying to do is this:

```
Response.write("<script language=""text/JavaScript"">document.cookie = '" & Cookie & " = ; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';</script>")
```

That is: Delete a cookie with the name stored in the ASP variable 'cookie'.  This doesn't work either, which is why I'm attempting to create the alert box just to test where I'm screwing up.

I've tried deleting the cookie with pure ASP (Response.cookie(Cookie).expires = Now() - 1), but since I made the cookie with JavaScript, it's not HTTPOnly so I can't access it with ASP.  (I just learned this, so I'm not 100% on the why of it all, but there it is.)

So, back to the first line of code, why am I not seeing a JavaScript alert box with that line of code?  I'm obviously missing something simple (it's always something simple).

Comment: You should be able to access the cookie from the server, HTTP-Only or not.

Comment: When is the first line processed? JavaScript won't just run when injected into the page. It needs an event to trigger it.

Comment: Similiar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556025/javascript-function-says-that-is-undefined

Comment: @Pointy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999360/how-do-i-set-the-httponly-flag-of-a-cookie-with-javascript  <-- That's where I gleamed that tidbit of information.

Comment: @JGGR13 you made an incorrect inference - HTTPOnly means that only the server can read the cookies; if that's not set, then both the server and the client can read it.

Comment: @Pointy: Fair enough.  Sorry for the confusing, I'm (re)learning web dev.

Comment: @isherwood What are you talking about? Of course you can run code that's injected. How else is code run?

Comment: @Ian, I didn't say injected code couldn't be run. I said it needs a trigger of some sort. You can't simply paste code into a page after load and expect it to do anything. Hence my initial question.

Comment: @isherwood And I don't understand what you mean by "it needs a trigger of some sort". If you put a block of `<script>` on the page, it will run as soon as the browser encounters it. It doesn't need an event. If you're using `Response.write`, all it does is at it to the text response, and therefore the browser will run it when it processes it. And as the answer proves, the problem had nothing to do with needing to be "triggered", it was simply a typo. I still don't understand what you mean

Comment: You're correct. I misunderstood what was happening in the OP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `language=""` attribute for `<script/>`-tags is deprecated and erroneous values prevent scripts from being executed in many browsers.

To me it looks like you were heading for the `type=""` attribute.

Try the following code:

```
Response.write("<script type=""text/javascript"">alert(""What up dog"");</script>")
```

Comment: Thank you very much Cobra_Fast.  Apparently it's been too damn long since I wrote anything for the web.  Old dogs, new tricks and all that.  And FTR: That solved my cookie deletion issue as well.